# merging two data frames with different number of row without repeating row

Tags: r

suppose I have two data frames named df and df1:

```
df<- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5),"occ"=c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2))

df1<- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),"salary"= c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19))
```

I want to merge two data based on `ID`  in such a way that if some row that exist in df1 but in df get zero . my expected output is like this:

```
   id occ salary
1   1   1     10
2   1   1     11
3   1   2      0
4   2   2     12
5   2   2     13
6   3   1     14
7   3   1     15
8   4   2     16
9   4   2     17
10  5   1     18
11  5   2     19
12  5   2      0
```

I tried by following code but it repeated row :

```
merged   <- merge(df, df1, by.x="id", by.y="id") or
merged   <- merge(df, df1, by = "id", all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a *time* variable missing, try this in base R.

```
> merge(
+   transform(df, time=ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along)),
+   transform(df1, time=ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along)),
+   all=TRUE
+ )
   id time occ salary
1   1    1   1     10
2   1    2   1     11
3   1    3   2     NA
4   2    1   2     12
5   2    2   2     13
6   3    1   1     14
7   3    2   1     15
8   4    1   2     16
9   4    2   2     17
10  5    1   1     18
11  5    2   2     19
12  5    3   2     NA
```

If you **really** want to replace `NA` with `0`, pipe it in a `replace`.

```
> merge(
+   transform(df, time=ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along)),
+   transform(df1, time=ave(id, id, FUN=seq_along)),
+   all=TRUE
+ ) |> transform(salary=replace(salary, is.na(salary), 0))
   id time occ salary
1   1    1   1     10
2   1    2   1     11
3   1    3   2      0
4   2    1   2     12
5   2    2   2     13
6   3    1   1     14
7   3    2   1     15
8   4    1   2     16
9   4    2   2     17
10  5    1   1     18
11  5    2   2     19
12  5    3   2      0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), occ = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
> dput(df1)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), salary = c(10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sequence of IDs is important for merging, you'll want to add an additional column. For example

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=id) %>% 
  left_join(df1 %>% mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=id), by = join_by(id, seq)) %>% 
  select(-seq) %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~coalesce(.x, 0)))
```

this returns

```
   id occ salary
1   1   1     10
2   1   1     11
3   1   2      0
4   2   2     12
5   2   2     13
6   3   1     14
7   3   1     15
8   4   2     16
9   4   2     17
10  5   1     18
11  5   2     19
12  5   2      0
```

Comment: thanks but I got error: Error in `context_peek()...

Comment: What version of `dplyr` do you have installed? This was tested with `dplyr_1.1.4`

Comment: I use 1.0.7, should I update that?

Comment: `install.packages("dplyr")` should update to the latest version. Do you have `plyr` loaded as well? That might be a problem. I've never seen an error for `context_peek` before.

Comment: as you said the `plyr` is the problem